# UITableView Reusing Content from Different Sections

Tags: ios, uitableview

My TableView has three different sections. Section 0 is for photo uploads its virtually empty until a user uploads a photo. However, my tableview is reusing cells from section 1 in section 2 and i'm not sure why. Here is the code below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";


if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    UploadsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UploadsCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.imageInfo = [_uploads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setCellInfo];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


    return cell;
}
else{

    id object;


    if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        object = [self cacheObjectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        return [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath withObject:object];

    }

    if (indexPath.section == 2) {

        object = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }

    return [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath withObject:object];

}

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withMobiObject:(MobiObject *)object{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


StylesCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = (StylesCell*)[[StylesCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if (object) {

    [cell setObject:object];
}
return cell;

}
```

Comment: Your code is a disaster. Why are you testing sections so irregularly? Why not use an if, else if, and else statement to check the section, or a switch?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this. Can you show me how to implement the switch statement

Comment: Yes I can, but first, why is the `object = [self cacheObjectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` in section 1, but `object = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` in section 2. Might this have an effect on the cell returned?

Comment: Well I have some cached objects stored on the phone and the object objects are returned from the web. I know the problem is in this area because the cached objects are being reused in section 2 when section 2 is only for objects from the web

Comment: it works perfectly when there's only one section, either the web objects or the cached objects but not both

Comment: If you are new to programming and / or iOS then I strongly suggest you follow a tutorial that will teach you the basics and the frameworks.  Try `Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad` for `Objective-C` or `Developing iOS 8 Apps with Swift` for `Swift` both of which are on iTunes U (a separate app on iOS or in iTunes on Mac / PC).

Comment: As an aside, don't cache tableview cells yourself - the frameworks re-use them. Always get a cell reference using the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method (it can be a different type of cell in each section) and then set the cell properties before returning the cell.

Answer (score 1):

You should first begin by making your methods a bit more readable. Since you've asked me for it, I've rewritten one of your larger methods to use a switch when returning the correct configuration for cells based on their section.

As for your actual problem, it's very likely associated with the following lines returning the configuration for Section 1:

```
id object = [self cacheObjectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
return [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath withObject:object];
```

As well as the other line returning configuration for Section 2:

```
id object = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
return [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath withObject:object];
```

I'm not sure exactly what these methods return, so it's hard to say what exactly about them is returning duplicate cells.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            // Section is Zero
            UploadsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.tag = indexPath.row;
            cell.delegate = self;
            cell.imageInfo = [_uploads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [cell setCellInfo];
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            return cell;

        case 1:
            // Section is One
            id object = [self cacheObjectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            return [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath withObject:object];

        case 2:
            // Section is Two
            id object = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            return [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath withObject:object];

        default:
            // Section is neither of the aforementioned sections.
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to sleep now as I'm deliriously tired, but sometime tomorrow I'll be back if need be.